# Trying to get a track list of an album on WikiData

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get the tracklist of an album on Wikidata.
I've tried in a few ways, but it didn't work.

This one didn't return any results:

```
SELECT ?track ?trackLabel WHERE {
       ?track wdt:P1433 wd:Q200872. #Q200872 The album Wish You Were Here by Pink Floyd
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }  
}
```

Then I tried this, which returned only 2 results:

```
SELECT ?track ?trackLabel WHERE {
       ?track wdt:P1433 wd:Q208227.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }  
}
```

I've tried this which works for some, but not for all:

```
SELECT ?album ?albumLabel WHERE {
       wd:Q151114 wdt:P658 ?album.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }  
}
```

What is the correct way to get an album's tracklist?

Comment: are you sure that such data exists for all albums? I mean, just search for some songs on that album and check if they are somehow linked to the album in Wikidata. Like sometimes here is an outgoing tracklist starting from the album entity, but not always. Sometimes it's modeled as "part of" relation, i.e. `?track wdt:P361 wd:Q200872.`

Comment: Thank you. Using P361 works better with some of the queries. It seems that the track listing of albums is somewhat inconsistent.